# How much loot can you gain per day?

Tags: clash-of-clans, clash-of-clans-builder-base

After attacking a few times and getting a bunch of loot, a message popped up saying I earned all the loot I could for the day. I wasn't really paying attention to how much loot I got, and I was spending it about as fast a I got it to upgrade new stuff, so I don't know how much I got. So, how much loot can you earn per day?

Answer (score 1):

The amount of loot (Gold and Elixir) that you earn per attack is based on the number of trophies you currently have. As of **May 26th 2017**, the *known* loot amounts for Gold *and* Elixir, per trophy level are:

```
 Trophies | 1 & 2 Attacks | 3rd Attack |      Total
---------------------------------------------------
        0 |        10,000 |     25,000 |     45,000
      200 |        15,000 |     30,000 |     60,000
      300 |        20,000 |     35,000 |     75,000
      400 |        25,000 |     40,000 |     90,000
      500 |        30,000 |     45,000 |    105,000
      600 |        35,000 |     50,000 |    120,000
      700 |        40,000 |     55,000 |    135,000
      800 |        45,000 |     60,000 |    150,000
      900 |        50,000 |     70,000 |    170,000
    1,000 |        60,000 |     80,000 |    200,000
    1,200 |        65,000 |     85,000 |    215,000
    1,400 |        70,000 |     90,000 |    230,000
    1,600 |        75,000 |    100,000 |    250,000
    1,800 |        80,000 |    110,000 |    270,000
    2,000 |        90,000 |    120,000 |    300,000
```

Your current loot levels can be confirmed by:

1. Pressing the "*Attack*" button from your Builder Base.
2. On the "*Wins*" panel (Below the "*Versus Battle*" panel), click the blue info (`i`) icon.

*Just take care not to press the "Get More Now" gem button when doing so!  They are VERY close together.*

Answer (score 0):

If you go to attack, at the bottom there is a message saying **"All loot won for today! More available in: (24H time period)"** - Every 24 hours it seems to reset.

If you click the [ i ] **info button** above the gems (to reset the timer) you can see your total possible loot per day. **This is based off of your trophies.**

I currently have 422 trophies and my win bonus is 25,000 gold, 25,000 elixir. The 3 win bonus is 40,000 of each.

By reaching 500 trophies, those numbers go up to 30,000 and 45,000 respectively. I imagine that continues to scale, just like the bonuses in the normal game.

Note: You can continue to attack and earn trophies, but you will not earn loot until the timer resets or you reset it via gems.